# How to invert (transpose) the rows and columns of an HTML table which is generated dynamically from highchair in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/export-data/showtable/

In the above example, I have created the highchart table using below code.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'A demo of displaying a data table in Highcharts'
},

credits: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

chart: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    spacingBottom: 30
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
}, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
}, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}],

exporting: {
    showTable: true
}

});
```

In above part,

```
 exporting: {
        showTable: true
    }
```

this part is responsible for generating highchart data table. The table I am getting should be revert i.e. rows to column and column to rows.

I have tried to convert this using javascript dom manipulation, but I need to some specific approach for the highchart only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside API there is no function to switch rows and columns only for exporting table. Change is possible with all data at module data  [data.switchRowsAndColumns](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.switchRowsAndColumns) but it's not your case I think.

You can try to change the core and use extending approach [how to extending Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

Find this `Chart.prototype.getTableAST` inside https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.src.js

Old version example showing how to wrap core and change the way to create table at export: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/npwjxkuL/